# Thymeleaf: Message as a parameter to another Message

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm new to Thymeleaf and am moving some facelets pages to use Thymeleaf. Due to the legacy system I am on we are using Thymeleaf 2.1.5 with an xml config.

I have run into an issue that I have struggled to find adequate documentation for. What I am trying to accomplish is taking localized messages as parameters in other messages.

One example that I have in several templates is something like this

```
Some text string <a href="url">CLICK HERE</a>
```

Where the properties file is like this:

```
some.text=Some text string {0} 
click.here=CLICK HERE
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
<p th:utext="#{some.text('<a th:utext="#{click.here}" href="url">')}"></p>
```

but had no luck getting it to work.

Also, is there a way to localize a string and without it being part of its own dom element? For example, I want to place a single string like this:

```
String
```

Instead of this:

```
<div> String </div>
```

Any insights would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works with Thymeleaf 3 for your specific example:

```
<p th:with="openTag='<a href=\'stackoverflow.com\'>',anchorLabel=#{click.here},closeTag='</a>'" th:remove="tag" th:utext="#{some.text(${openTag+anchorLabel+closeTag})}"></p>
```

Unfortunately, producing *double* quotes around the link in the output doesn't seem to work.  Don't know whether Thymeleaf supports this.  I'll update if I find a way.  Single quotes seem to work though.

But in general, you're likely looking for some combination of `th:with` to create variables.  As far as your second question, you will want to use `th:remove="tag"` to remove tags.

Answer assumes a config like:

```
@Bean
public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {

    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setOrder(1);
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public ITemplateResolver webTemplateResolver() {

    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/thymeleaf/");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setCacheable(false);
    resolver.setOrder(2);
    return resolver;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I believe you have gotten me nearly there but I get this error: The value of attribute "th:with" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character. Is there a way to fix this while still using unescaped text?

Comment: are one of your values that you are supplying null?  I'd look at `click.here`

Comment: click.here is not null as far as I can tell. I can use it without the parameters just fine. I thought maybe the '<' needed to be escaped in some manner but am not sure.

Comment: Found that removing '<' allows it to function. Just need the escaped values for '<' and '>'. '&#60;' and '&#62;' respectively.

Comment: Ok, the other thing to note is that in my config for the resolver, I use TemplateMode.HTML with a CharacterEncoding of UTF-8.

Comment: I'm on Thymeleaf 2.1.5 with an xml config due to the legacy system I am working with. I believe I have the analogous configurations.

Comment: Thinking that the older version would explain that discrepancy

Comment: A more reasonable escape sequence can also be found here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360009/error-parsing-thymeleaf-template-with-1-0

Answer (score 0):

You should really split the text generation with i18n and the link. You can wrap the 'some.text' in a span and render the link after that. Like this you avoid `utext` and can properly generate the link with a translated text also if that's desired.

One way to avoid having the span in the resulting html would be to use the attribute `th:remove="tag"`.

Another solution should now be possible by using a `<th:block>...</>` element, if I'm not mistaken, so you don't need to remove a tag after again.

```
<span th:remove="tag" th:text="#{some.text}">some text that will be replaced but shows in the mock</span> <a href="url" th:text="#{click.me}">CLICK HERE</a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think splitting it up is an option.

Comment: Why would that not be possible? Dont you have full control on the template and message creation?