# Thymeleaf does not allow "lt" as query string parameter name

Tags: thymeleaf

I cannot use "lt" as query string parameter name in thymeleaf. How can I achieve that?

This is my example code:

```
<a th:href="@{/payment/otp-resend(lt=${landingToken.sessionId})}" class="sifretekrar" th:text="#{lp.resendOtp}"></a>
```

And it gives the following error:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "@{/payment/otp-resend(lt=${landingToken.sessionId})}" (template: "otp-entry-page" - line 70, col 12)
at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:131)
at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:62)
at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:44)
at org.thymeleaf.engine.EngineEventUtils.parseAttributeExpression(EngineEventUtils.java:220)
at org.thymeleaf.engine.EngineEventUtils.computeAttributeExpression(EngineEventUtils.java:207)
at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:125)
at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205)
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136)
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:661)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362)
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1370)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1116)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
```

Best regards.

**EDIT**

The accepted answer is correct. However, Intellij IDEA shows it as if it has an error. The screenshot is attached below. The following two lines are working while IDE displays error message for both of them:

```
<a th:href="@{/payment/mps-otp-resend} + '?lt=' + ${landingToken.sessionId}" class="sifretekrar" th:text="#{lp.resendOtp}"></a>

<a th:href="@{/payment/mps-otp-resend('lt'=${landingToken.sessionId})}" class="sifretekrar" th:text="#{lp.resendOtp}"></a>
```

[image: screenshot of IDE error]

Comment: I guess it gives an error because of the keywords lt, gt and etc. Please have a look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360009/error-parsing-thymeleaf-template-with-1-0 (Section 2.6 Under Comparisons and equality)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quote `lt`,  which should allow you to use it as a parameter name:

```
<a th:href="@{/payment/otp-resend('lt'=${landingToken.sessionId})}" class="sifretekrar" th:text="#{lp.resendOtp}"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you this is working. I didn't try that before I got this answer because my IDE (Intellij IDEA) was showing error for this use.