# Thymeleaf check if variable equals a number

Tags: thymeleaf

I have the following Thymeleaf code, I want "--" to be printed if taxHistory.landValue equals to zero, and the actual value to be printed if taxHistory.landValue is greater than 0

```
<td th:if"${taxHistory.landValue==0}" th:text="--"></td>
<td th:unless="${taxHistory.landValue>0}" th:text="|${taxHistory.landValue}|"></td>
```

However I'm getting the following error

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "0}"
```

What is the correct way of doing this in Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, but you can use a ternary operator and print your string if your desired condition does not match:

```
<td th:text="${taxHistory.landValue &gt; 0 ? taxHistory.landValue : '--' }">[taxHistory.landValue]</td>
```

You can use the `&gt;` notation to keep the [HTML formed properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360009/error-parsing-thymeleaf-template-with-1-0).  This assumes that a negative value would also print your string (you didn't mention behavior in that unusual case).

Comment: works well, do you know how we can add a string to `>[taxHistory.landValue]<`? I want to add a dollar sign behind it. I added it manually but it's not showing up on the webpage.

Comment: Take a look at this post (and my updated answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160304/how-to-format-the-currency-in-html5-with-thymeleaf

Comment: Note that what you have in your comment is the default value that would show if you just opened the HTML page in a browser.  It would not be shown if the page is served on a server/container.  It's best practice to add this default value so that you can see what the page looks like without serving up the page.  This works well for UI designers.

Comment: Would something like this work? https://pastebin.com/kJmUg1NV I'm trying to get the result of the one line if statement into a variable then print it inline. It's giving an error now though.

Comment: Are you simply attempting to add a currency symbol to your evaluated value?  Or do you somehow want to add a currency symbol to the default value (what appears between the tags without running a server)?

Comment: in the former case, something like this (untested):  `<td th:with="totalAssessment=${taxHistory.landValue + taxHistory.additions}" 
    th:text=${totalAssessment &gt; 0 ? #numbers.formatCurrency(result) : '--' }">[total assessment]</td>`

Comment: I'd always try to make it as simple as possible... it's a nightmare to maintain otherwise :)